# How to Minimize Run Time: Value Replacement Iterations in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a dataframe called df_override that contains the "name", "Field", and "New Value" columns. The aim of this loop is to replace all "name" matches in the df dataframe's "Field" column to the "New Value". The if statement is to see if it's an integer, then it would match by the "id" column instead.

This loop works fine but with a large dataframe it gets unbelievably slow. I have several other for loops that run just like this later in the function. I am wondering if there is any other way to perform this function that's optimized for run time?

Thanks.

```
for index, row in df_override.iterrows():
    if(not str(row["name"]).isdigit()):
        df.loc[df["name"] == row["name"], row["Field"]] = row["New Value"]
    else:
        df.loc[df["id"] == row["name"], row["Field"]] = row["New Value"]
```

```
df_override
"name"  "Field"  "New Value"
apple    color     red
100     is_number  True

df
"name" "id" "color"  "is_number"
apple   300   blue      False
apple   200   yellow    False
banana  100   green     False

df (after processing)
"name" "id" "color"  "is_number"
apple  300    red       False
apple  200    red       False
banana 100    green     True
```

Comment: where's `df['id']` in your `else:` clause?

Comment: @quang-hoang sorry. updated.

Answer (score 0):

Changing it to values instead of iterrow improved performance but it's still slow.

New Loop

```
for field, name, value in zip(df_override["Field"].values,df_override["name"].values,df_override["New Value"].values):
    if not str(name).isdigit():
        df[field] = np.where(df["name"]  == name, df[field], value)
    else:
        df[field] = np.where(df["id"]  == name, df[field], value)
```